# How to create a makefile with a shell script

Tags: makefile

I have a shell script, and would like to convert it to a makefile so that it can be executed with the command 'make all'.

How would I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a minimal makefile containing:

```
all:
        YOUR SHELL COMMANDS HERE
```

But you haven't really gained anything by doing so unless you rewrite it to make use of some of the features of a Makefile - multiple targets, target dependencies, etc. See [here](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) (or many other Makefile tutorials) for some information about what you can do with a makefile.

(Note that the shell commands are executed with `sh` separately for each line, so if you're doing anything complex like loops, setting variables it won't *just work*, and the indentation of commands needs to be a TAB character, not spaces.)

A quick Makefile for the case described (normal warnings, probably has all sorts of edge cases, might kill your dog, etc):

```
src=$(wildcard pictures/*.jpg)
out=$(subst pictures,thumb,$(src))

all : $(out)

thumb/%.jpg: pictures/%.jpg
    convert $< -thumbnail 100 $@
```

Comment: #! /bin/bash

cd pictures
for i in *.jpg; do
    if [ "$i" -nt "../thumbs/$i" ]; then
        convert "$i" -thumbnail 100 "../thumbs/$i";
    fi
done; That's the shell script. What can do so that the script can be called with 'make all'. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: If I run  it with./filename it runs, but I want to be able to run it with make all

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you separate your shell scripts out into several parts. E.g. prebuild, build, postbuild. Several small tasks make it easier to test the script.

```
clean:
  rm -rf build

build:
  gcc sample.c

changelog:
  git log >> changelog.txt

package: changelog build
  zip release.zip a.out changelog.txt 

all: clean package
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clean:
  @-rm -rf build
  @echo removed 

build:
  gcc sample.c

changelog:
  git log >> changelog.txt

package: changelog build
  zip release.zip a.out changelog.txt 

all: clean package
```